# Set State erasing previous object value React

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to make subsequent API calls to get infos about some financial indexes.. After each call, I want to update de indexObject so it has all the data from all the indexes I stored on the indexes array. The problem is, each time setIndexObject is called it overwrites the object, loosing the previous value even when i use the spread operator.

```
 const [indexObject, setIndexObject] = useState({});

  const indexes = [
    "^GDAXI",
    "^BVSP",
    "^NDX",
    "^DJI",
    "^GSPC",
    "^IBEX",
    "^HSI",
    "^BSESN",
    "^FTSE",
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    indexes.forEach((index) => {
      const options = {
        method: "GET",
        url:
          "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-summary",
        params: { symbol: `${index}`, region: "US" },
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "----",
          "x-rapidapi-host": "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        },
      };

      axios
        .request(options)
        .then(function (response) {
          setIndexObject({
            ...indexObject,
            [index]: {
              value: response.data.price.regularMarketPrice.fmt,
              variation: response.data.price.regularMarketChangePercent.fmt,
            },
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
  }, []);
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
{
    A:{
      value:,
      variation:,
    },
    B:{
      value:,
      variation,
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are adding and removing similar objects like this, wouldn't an array of objects be a better data type for your state?

Comment: When using the current state to update the state, always use the callback version of `setState`. Also, is the axios call in a `useEffect`?

Comment: what is index and how are you updating it ? it seems the index prop is not changing

Comment: may I know where is that [`index`] coming from? and how do you call this axios request (clicking button or useffect or what)?

Comment: I'll post the full code to make things clear, one sec

Comment: Did you tried replacing ...indexObject with  ...this.state.indexObject

Comment: @DBS I guess.. But for the sake of curiosity i would like to understand why this is not working

Comment: Original value of indexObject is getting captured by the closure. Use the callback form of setState mentioned above so that you get the current value when trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're looping the request, while the `setState` is not synchronous. It is better to populate all the data first, then set the state after that.

```js
const [indexObject, setIndexObject] = useState({});

const handleFetchData = async () => {
  const indexes = [
    "^GDAXI",
    "^BVSP",
    "^NDX",
    "^DJI",
    "^GSPC",
    "^IBEX",
    "^HSI",
    "^BSESN",
    "^FTSE",
  ];
  const resultData = {};

  for(const index of index) {
    const response = await axios.request(); // add your own request here
    
    resultData[index] = response;
  }

  return resultData;
}

useEffect(() => {
  handleFetchData().then(data => setIndexObject(data));
}, []);
```

why i use `for of`? because `forEach` or `.map` cannot await asynchronous loop.
Or if you want to fetch all the data simultaneously, you can consider using `Promise.all`

Comment: Thanks! It worked using setState callback function but this way works better!